# Make app open chrome by default

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-permissions, chrome-custom-tabs

I have an app that open a link in a chrome custom tab. But when the user runs it for the first time(and he has multiple browsers installed), it gives the user a popup asking him to choose the default application (i.e do you wanna set UCBrowser as default, or chrome etc)

Is there someway I can skip this popup and always open in chrome for my app?

Comment: Just want to make sure you understand that Chrome might not be installed on the device.

Comment: we have an explicit check beforehand. If chrome is not installed we proceed in a web view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `PackageManager` for this

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");
launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
if (launchIntent != null) {
    context.startActivity(launchIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Chrome not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Or you can just use `setPackage` method on `Intent`

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent();
launchIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
launchIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
launchIntent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

but before setPackage you have to ensure that package exists (com.android.chrome in your case)